# Centre of Mass of Particle System in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, particles

I have a large set of data of x,y,z coordinates and molar masses for a particle system. I want to take the system and get a centre of mass out of it, but I can't seem to find any existing function for it. In the hopes of not reinventing the wheel since it seems like something that might exist I figured I'd ask here. And failing that, a smart way to do it than won't take a ton of computation time as I'm going to need to do it about 30 million times over systems of 23 or so particles many times over.

All data is currently in an array, in the format of [x, y, z, m], where m is the mass.

```
import numpy
from scipy import ndimage
a = numpy.array(([0.5,1.0,-1.0,0.5],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],[-1.0,1.0,0,1.0],[-1.5,1.5,0.5,0.5]))
```

There's a sample set of data, and if I use the scipy centre of mass function it spits out a tuple:

```
ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(a)

Out[4]: (1.2857142857142858, 2.0714285714285716)
```

I'm at a loss as to what the tuple means, the scipy documentation on it is dreadfully unclear to me, much too spare. I would have expected a tuple of three values, since I gave it three dimensional data, which I'm assuming it just doesn't understand. And giving it a 0,0,0,0 vector as the first value as in their first example doesn't help, it just changes the value of the two numbers. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As to why you get a tuple: Your data is interpreted as a 4x4 2D image, therefor you get 2 coordinates

Comment: You may find [this](http://ifcuriousthenlearn.com/blog/2015/06/18/center-of-mass/) interesting.

Comment: @FlyingTeller ok, so how can I have it interpreted properly?